# Can't login to Linux VM created by custom image

Tags: linux, azure

I have created a custom image of Debian 7.0 following this blog post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dcaro/archive/2014/12/03/create-your-azure-image-with-debian-7-0.aspx

In the management portal the VM status is running. But I can't log into the VM using ssh. What's the possible cause and how to solve it?

I intend to create a VM image of FreeBSD 8.3 in Azure. Any one has tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can find official FreeBSD 10.2 images on VM Depot, created by FreeBSD team (https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/Vhd/Show?vhdId=56718&version=58911) so it is possible to do it with 8.3 i think. Maybe ask FreeBSD team on VM Depot?
About Debian: are You sure that You have run hose commands?

```
sudo waagent -force -deprovision
export HISTSIZE=0
logout
```

If Yes, and something is still wrong with SSH or user, try to use cloud-init (https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/cloud-init). Install it on the image, and during provisioning from CLI tool (https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) add option --custom-data ~/cloud.cfg at the end. In this file You must put Cloud-Config:

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - name: username
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa <key here>
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
```

It will create user "username" with desired SSH key overwriting user/pass options from Azure command.

Answer (score -1):

maybe the iptables setting , try to disable iptables.